# Can you be seen under the effects of Etherealness on the material plane?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

If you cast [*Etherealness*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/etherealness) on yourself, and then go dance naked in front of a guard (or anything else) could they see you, if so would you appear see-through and etherial or could you pass off as a normal person assuming you move your legs as if you are walking and don't clip through anything/one.

Comment: It seems like you could have found the answer to this question by simply reading the spell description.

Answer (score 4):

### Nope, the guard will not see you (ordinarily)

The spell Etherealness says:

> Creatures that aren't on the Ethereal Plane can't perceive you and
> can't interact with you, unless a special ability or magic has given
> them the ability to do so.

An example of magic that *would* allow someone on the material plane to perceive you is the [See Invisibility](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/see-invisibility) spell. So if you don't want to be arrested for indecent exposure, you better hope the guard does not have this ability.

It should be noted that the Ethereal Plane has two "aspects" to it (PHB, Planes of Existence section in the part about the Transitive Planes): The Deep Ethereal - an area of mists and colourful fogs - and the Border Ethereal - the part of the plane that "overlaps" the material plane.

The Ethereal spell states that you are transported to is this border area, allowing you to see into the material plane (as stated in the spell) but not the other way around as previously mentioned

Answer (score 2):

The description of the spell states (emphasis mine):

> While on the Ethereal Plane, you can only affect and be affected by other creatures on that plane. **Creatures that aren't on the Ethereal Plane can't perceive you and can't interact with you, unless a special ability or magic has given them the ability to do so.**

Hence the guard can not see you, unless they have some special ability or they are under some spells such as [*True Seeing*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/true-seeing).

---

Pay attention that you can not clip through creatures: the DMG (pag 48) says (emphasis mine)

> A traveler on the Ethereal Plane is invisible and utterly silent to someone on the overlapped plane, and solid objects on the overlapped plane don't hamper the movement of a creature in the Border EthereaL
> The exceptions are certain magical effects (including anything made of magical force) and **living beings**.

The  Etherealness spell does not override this general rule, its description does not mention creatures (emphasis mine):

> You ignore all objects and effects that aren't on the Ethereal Plane, allowing you to **move through objects** you perceive on the plane you originated from.